# Searching a node in two deques simultaneously and printing the values in the queues - Python 3

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, deque

I have a code for a Breadth-first Search search algorithm.

[image]

According to the 3rd last line of the algorithm, we have to check if the child state is already available in both the queues before performing any further action. In my code, I have to make BFS algorithm to search for a path from start-point to end-point in a maze. I have made a node that saves state, actions, path and parent for a grid location. The code is as follows:

```
#class to initialize node
class Node:
    state = []
    actions = []
    parent = []
    path = 0
    
    def __init__(self, state, actions, parent, path):
        self.state = state
        self.actions = actions
        self.parent = parent
        self.path = path
```

In the algorithm function, I am adding nodes from a start point to a deque in Python. But before adding I have to check for the condition that child.state should not be in frontier or explored queues. My condition in the code runs infinitely. It is as follows:

```
def bfs_search(maze_size, start_point, end_point, grid_values, number_of_grids):
    
    #code for creating first node and adding to queue
 
    
    while True:
            #here we have the code to break the loop if queue gets empty and then finding the child 
             pointer and creating child notes

            #this condition does not execute as it should
            if child_node.state not in frontier and child_node.state not in explored:
                if child_node.state == end_point:
                    goal = True
                    explored.appendleft(child_node)
                    break
                else:
                    frontier.appendleft(child_node)
```

I also want to print the elements appended to the queue while testing the code to check if the nodes are being appended to the queue.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without seeing the full code. In the code you posted I don't see where you remove nodes from `frontier`. I do not know if this is done in some other part of the code that you haven't posted, or if you never remove from the queue (which would explain why the loop never terminates, since the queue would never get empty). Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we don't have to guess what happens in the part of the code you haven't posted.

Comment: Some general notes: You mentioned two queues, `frontier` and `explored`. In a usual BFS implementation, `explored` would not be represented as a queue. In your pseudo-code it is declared as a set. You could represent this for example as a `set` in Python, or come up with some other data structure, such as having a boolean flag for each node that you can set/check in constant time.